# List comprehension over map object that accesses property

Tags: python, properties

I have the following list comprehension:

```
preprocessed_video = preprocess(video)
timestamps = [frame.timestamp for frame in preprocessed_video]
```

The collection is always empty, even though there are `frames` with their corresponding timestamp value initialized. `video` is a map object, consisting on a collection of `frames`, coming from another a preprocessing function, and a `frame` is a class with a `timestamp` property:

```
def preprocess(video):
    return map(fun, video) # fun returns a Frame

class Frame():
    __init(..., timestamp)__:
        self._timestamp = timestamp
    ...
    @property
    def timestamp():
        return self._timestamp
```

If on `preprocess(video)` I return a list like `list(map(fun, video))`, the timestamp list comprehension does have values. However, if I return just a map, I just get an empty list. Why is this happening?

Comment: how are you calling preprocess and storing it? you pass video, to preprocess and return a map, then you use video in your list comprehension, but it seems you would want to use the map you returned from preprocessing?

Comment: yeah exactly: I am using the output from the preprocess video on the list comprehension. I am gonna edit the question to showcase it better